# Specifying a 2 px Width for columns in Bootstrap CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I need to have a `td` which will hold just a two digit number and am trying to see a 2 px width.

`style="width:2px;"`

How do I define it with bootstrap CSS without using the px?

Comment: If you want a 2 pixel width, you'll have to use px measures. No way around it I think. What you are using seems fundamentally like the only way to go (depending on what kind of element it is, you may have to do additional clipping)

Comment: Let me explain you more clearly. I just want a column able to handle a two character width like 00 to 99 or capital W like WW. (which has maximum width consumption)

Comment: So you *don't* want 2 pixels width, but two characters? That's different - can you edit your question to make that more clear? Not sure this can be done perfectly in pure CSS, but who knows. You should also add the `css` tag to attract more experts

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I have added css and css3 to get more experts to collaborate on the topic.

Comment: OK, but you also need to edit the question so it says the correct thing.

Comment: @DeepakVasudevan check my jsfiddle please

Comment: Did my answer fixed your problem ? @DeepakVasudevan

Comment: I am using the 2 px for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the table table-layout: fixed; and then give to td whatever width you want. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8s0hs1kb/2/).

```
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}

td {
  width:2em;
}
```